# New to django, my terminal thinks that there is a syntax error with "path"

Tags: python-3.x, django

```
path('details/<int:pk>/', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name="article_details"),
```

my terminal thinks that there is syntax error here, specifically an arrow that points to the 'h' in 'path' i am running ubuntu 18.04 on a jetson nano, and this is in urls.py.
[terminal page after python3 manage.py runserver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KigWe.png)

Comment: Share the full `urls.py` and traceback.

Comment: make sure you have a comma for seperating the above path

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you import **path** from django URLs
which is: 
`from django.urls import path`

 
If you've already imported it. Check if you separate each URL's by a comma at the end of the line

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('details/<int:pk>/', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name="article_details"),
    path('login/', UserLoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
]
```